# WOL events during Linux runtime

Tags: linux, networking, wake-on-lan, udp, acpi

I want to be able to react to Wake-On-Lan packets sent to my machine while it is already booted.
I am able to turn my machine on using WOL, so the general system seems to work.
My question now is:

- Is there a way of receiving those WOL events while Linux is already booted?
- Does the BIOS/UEFI/Network card even send any WOL events the an already booted OS (Debian)?

I know I could listen to the WOL UDP packets, but was wondering if there is an easier solution.

Comment: https://wiki.wireshark.org/WakeOnLAN#capture-filter

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to listen to the port. A useful tool here is
[nc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc).

The post
[Wake-on-lan to trigger virtual-machine with kvm and libvirt](https://serverfault.com/questions/474199/wake-on-lan-to-trigger-virtual-machine-with-kvm-and-libvirt)
includes this useful bash snippet in the
[answer by Gotschi](https://serverfault.com/a/1079289/18736):

```
#!/bin/bash

nc -dknl -p 9 -u | # listen to udp port 9 for packets, check if it is a magic packet
 stdbuf -o0 xxd -c 6 -p |
 stdbuf -o0 uniq |
 stdbuf -o0 grep -v 'ffffffffffff' |
 while read ; do
     mac="${REPLY:0:2}:${REPLY:2:2}:${REPLY:4:2}:${REPLY:6:2}:${REPLY:8:2}:${REPLY:10:2}"
    # do something with the sender's mac found in the magic packet
    ...
done
```

---

As regarding the question of intercepting the WOL request,
this is discussed in the post
[How to recognize a WOL (Wake On Lan) request while the PC is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925586/how-to-recognize-a-wol-wake-on-lan-request-while-the-pc-is-running).

The comment by user Duston says :

> Wake-on-LAN is really a MAC-level thing, (although some implementations use UDP) so you'd really have to listen to the raw packets as they come across...assuming the NIC passes that packet along to the NIC drivers. It isn't the software that turns on the computer when the packet is received, it's a signal from the NIC to the motherboard that does. In short, I don't think you're going to find an easy answer.

This was further discussed in the accepted
[answer by OldFrank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31012975/165358):

> I agree with Duston that WOL is a Layer 2 combined with hardware thing. On a normal working PC, there is little chance that the NIC hardware will pass this on to the drivers, as it is exactly the task of this hardware to only disturb your CPU if really needed.
> You best chance to see a magic packet on a working PC would be : install and run sniffer (packet analyzer) software. That will force a supportive NIC into a special mode that transfers every packet to the CPU. If you can now see the magic packet in the output, next step would be to configure the sniffer to alert you in case it sees a magic packet. Done. All this will be quite CPU-intensive.
> You could write software that performs all this, but that would essentially be rewriting the complete sniffer with fixed query instead of a configurable one.

Comment: Thanks, but I explicitly asked about an alternative. I was hoping there would be an acpi event or alike...

Comment: I added more information to my answer as regarding this subject.

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick